# How detailed should I be in my bachelor thesis about data visualization and xai about the performance of specific models?

Tags: thesis, bachelor

I have another question regarding my bachelor's thesis.
I built a data visualization and explainable ai tool.
Now for that, I have integrated some basic machine-learning models for users to interact with.

I included the basic hyperparameters and results, but I feel that is really not so important and I wonder if I include too much because the performance isn't really important for my project. I wasn't going to include it at all in the beginning but my Professor gave me some feedback, not specific on this part but in general that I should elaborate on the solution more and make my contribution clear.

Additionally, if I report the results, should I also upload scripts that readers can use to reproduce?
I have them but they're not pretty and this is another reason I honestly don't want to go into too much detail because it adds a lot of extra work for something that isn't entirely relevant (it wouldn't matter if the performance was better or worse) to the project.

Thanks a lot for your advice in advance

Comment: This kind of question is what advisors are for. So just ask her/him. We don't know what is going to factor into your grade, your advisor does. If we think it should not be there, and your advisor does think it should be there, than whose opinion is going to count?

Comment: @MaartenBuis thanks, I know and that is a good point. Unlike the usual where my peers have a PhD as advisor I don't and my Professor wanted to supervise directly, I notice how busy they are and thus I am hesitant to check for things that I think might be a bit too trivial for them (but not for me). I think I'll try putting it somewhere in the appendix.

Comment: No, you should ask. If your professor wanted to supervise you directly, then answering that question became her/his/their job.

Answer (score 0):

You are both sub-optimizing and engaging in self-defeating behavior (sorry) if you don't work with your advisor making assumptions that they are "really" to busy to work with you when they have agreed to do so. It is a habit, perhaps, that you need to break.

How detailed you need to be is a local question since the thesis will be judged locally and such expectations vary greatly.

You have an opportunity to work with someone knowledgeable. Take advantage of it. Express to them, if you like, that you are a bit insecure in asking questions of them and then judge the response. They can, most likely, point you to resources you need without a lot of effort.

Note also, that in agreeing to supervise you directly, they have expressed some interest in you and your work. Take advantage of that.

To answer your headline question directly, how detailed you need to be depends on your field and topic and how you approach the topic. We can't evaluate your work, but your advisor can. You might need very little detail and you might need to be extremely detailed with anything in between possible.

---

Personal note: While it wasn't exactly the same issue, I went through a period in my studies when I didn't speak up when I should have (self defeating). It cost me three years of study and landed me in an extremely unfavorable academic market.